# How can I pass a model to the view when I use DD4T?

Tags: dd4t

I use dd4t and mvc. And I want to make queries from the controllers, make the components to view models and pass the model to the views. So when I try to pass the view model a get exception :

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyWebSite.ViewModels.ArticleViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DD4T.ContentModel.IPage'."

And I use the default mvc routing and I don't use the UnityDependencyResolver. I work from very soon with dd4t and I realy have no idea what else to do so I can solve this problem. Here is also the code from my controller

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Criteria criteria = new ItemSchemaCriteria(176);

        SortParameter param1 = new
        SortParameter(SortParameter.ItemCreationDate,
        SortParameter.Descending);
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
        query.AddSorting(param1);
        string[] results = query.ExecuteQuery();

        ComponentFactory cf = new ComponentFactory();
        cf.ComponentProvider = new TridionComponentProvider();
        var components = cf.GetComponents(results);

        List<ArticleViewModel> articles = components.AsQueryable()
                                                       .Select(ArticleViewModel
                                                       .FromArticleComponent)
                                                       .Take(7).ToList();

        return View(articles);
    }
}
```

Thanks and if you need more specifics, just tell me.

Comment: Could you also post the code from your corresponding cshtml file

Answer (score 6):

You are calling the view with a model of the type List. This is fine, just start your razor view with the line:

```
@model List<ArticleViewModel>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have the basic DD4T pipeline working - i.e. published content (using DD4T TBBS), a view corresponding to your page template and a view corresponding to your component template, page and component controllers?

Ultimately the view that the ViewEngine has found for this action - presumably */Views/Home/Index.cshtml* is expecting an `@model` of `DD4T.ContentModel.IPage` but your passing an IList.

How is this controller being called?

Any reason your not following the Visual Studio template to get going first?

Cheers